# How can I evaluating limits? $\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}(xe^{2x}+1)^{5/x}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi / 2}}(1+\sec(3x))^{\cot(x)}$

Tags: limits

Can someone please give me an idea how to do these two limits. I guess it is the L'Hopital's rule, not sure.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}(xe^{2x}+1)^{5/x}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow{\pi / 2}}(1+\sec(3x))^{\cot(x)}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest one way to do the first, and let you see about the second: Let $y = \left(xe^{2x} + 1\right)^{5/x}$. Then

$$\ln{y} = \frac{5}{x} \ln\left(xe^{2x} + 1\right)$$

By L'Hospital's rule,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{5 \ln\left(xe^{2x} + 1\right)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{5}{xe^{2x} + 1} \left(2xe^{x} + e^{2x}\right) = \frac{5(0 + 1)}{1} = 5$$

So $\ln{y} \to 5$, and $y \to e^{5}$.

Comment: I tried the second one and got $\frac{3\sec(3x)\tan(3x)}{\sec^2(x)(1+\sec(3x))}$. Please tell me where to go from here? Thanks

Comment: @seek Try converting everything into $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: I got a $\ln y \rightarrow 0$ so limit is $1$ is that correct please?

Comment: @seek [Seems to be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%281+%2B+sec%283x%29%29^%28cot%28x%29%29+at+pi%2F2).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Does that website evaluate limits in symbolic form?

Comment: @seek Yes, it does.